# In the US what are the requirements for drug manufacturers for pets, to list side effects

Tags: medicines, legal

A recent question [Cat suddenly became paralyzed](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/cat-suddenly-became-paralyzed?noredirect=1#comment28553_20998) has a cat with sudden onset paralysis, after starting a new drug.  The companies drug literature does not list this as a side effect, but the OP found that several pet owners had seen paralysis after administering the drug.

> although I did find pet-owners who had the same experience on related forums.

User comments suggest that as the side effect is not listed by the manufacture it could not possibly be related [1](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/cat-suddenly-became-paralyzed#comment28551_20998) & [2](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/cat-suddenly-became-paralyzed#comment28553_20998)

> You've done the research and there really isn't any reason to think there's a link between the felimazole and your cat's new symptoms.
>
> I'm referring to the listed side-effects from studies.

What are the actual legal requirements for pet medications?  Does the vet or the manufacture need to report this possible side effect?

Comment: this site might provide some of the information https://www.fda.gov/animalveterinary/resourcesforyou/ucm268128.htm

Comment: @trondhansen thank you, a side link from your source seems to indicate the answer, which is what my early research showed.  I was really hoping someone would post a "yes, there is a requirement" answer.

Comment: in the EU adverse effects are listed for each type of medication by the producers like this for felimazole http://www.noahcompendium.co.uk/?id=-449704&fromsearch=true#iosfirsthighlight but this do not answer what the regulations in the US are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, reporting is completely voluntary.

> The FDA **encourages** veterinarians and animal owners to report adverse drug experiences and product defects associated with animal drugs or animal devices [souce](https://www.fda.gov/AnimalVeterinary/SafetyHealth/ReportaProblem/ucm055305.htm) *emphisis mine*

There are no requirements for drug makers or veterinarians to report side effects.

You can't prove a negative, so this remains an open question.  I will happily modify or delete this answer if reputable sources for mandatory reporting are found.